# Supporting role: Group efficiency vs Table "fun balancing"

Tags: dnd-5e, problem-players, party

I'm playing a cleric in a 4-player group along with a paladin, a warlock/bladesinger melee multiclass, and a rogue. The paladin is level 5 and the rest of us are level 4.

The table uses stat rolling and while we all rolled better-than-average stats, the paladin rolled really, really well.

Now I find myself facing this dilemma: I could be casting *warding bond*, *shield of faith* and whatever other spell I'm using (I'm playing an Order Domain cleric, which grants allies reaction attacks when I target them with spells) on the paladin. Which is clearly the most efficient way to go about it, having a 21 AC monster on the field, resistant to all damage, destroying every melee opponent.

Or I could be casting my concentration buffs on the more mobile character, who rolled average stats, so he doesn't feel left out.

We have played 1 session so far, and the only encounter we had was pretty hard. I was forced to use all my spell slots; at one point the multiclassed character was knocked unconscious by 2 hits from hidden opponents. The 4th character, a rogue, failed the save against *hold person* and ate 2 full *fireball*s; the paladin and I barely saved him.

What would you guys do in this situation? I understand this is a moral question, and unlike the mechanical questions usually asked here, so I apologise if I unknowingly violated some rule regarding the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the issue you're facing? Are you saying that the "optimal" strategy for winning fights is to stack all your buffs on the most powerful character, but you're worried that doing so will make the other players feel left out?

Comment: This seems to be an opinion survey question. Also, the main factors involved are the party dynamic and how your fellow players would feel. Have you asked the players for feedback or their opinions?

Comment: @RyanThompson Yes, this is exactly the case

Comment: @MikeQ I have asked the multiclassing character, and he seemed... annoyed by how overpowered the rolls made the paladin, and we were joking after the session with him about how i could just stick behind the paladin buffing and healing him and we'd just duo the campaign.

Comment: So is the question whether you should prioritize supporting the stronger ally versus the weaker ally?  There's a strategic aspect to it, but if you want to account for players feeling left out, then strangers on the internet can't answer that for you.

Comment: There are very few questions in the [problem-players] tag that are not opinion based.  Is that the issue here, or is it more that the question is not clearly stated?

Comment: I think from how you state your question, the problem is obvious. But you need to tell us how your party react to the result of that encounter, else we can only guess and that's not expert opinion, after all.

Comment: Is the question: "We almost lost an encounter because I do this (only buffing paladin, OR did not buff paladin exclusively), and the party is now salty because of it" or "We almost lost an encounter because I do this, the party is fine, but I still feel bad because of my decision. Should I've buffed the paladin instead?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Put your concerns out in the open

This question concerns everyone at your table, including the GM, so it would be best to check in with your entire group. Just be straight up. "Hey, so the Paladin is way more powerful than the rest of us, how do you all think I should play my Cleric so this is fun for everyone?"

Its a simple straightforward question that should probably be resolved at your table, face to face.

What I'm guessing you'll find from the ensuing discussion is that you should switch it up as you see fit.

What you may not hear at the discussion but it's important to keep in mind is that any decent GM will provide opportunities for each character to shine. If you trust your GM, trust that the Rogue will be given ample opportunities to exhibit their talents in situations where the Paladin would fail epicly.